# Validar array JSON schema - usando JS

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

Galera, estou tentando realizar testes unitários com esse JSON schema:

```
"Transactions":{
                "$id": "http://example.com/example.json/items",
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {                    
                    "UUU" : {
                        "description": "Valor UUU",
                        "type": "array",
                        "minItems": 1,
                        "maxItems": 1,
                        "required": true,
                        "items":[
                            {
                            "quantity": {
                                "$id": "http://example.com/example.json/items",
                                "type": "object",
                                "additionalProperties": false,
                                "properties": {
                                    "ValUU": {
                                        "description": "Valor em UU",
                                        "$id": "http://example.com/example.json/items/properties/paragraphs/properties/impact",
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "title": "Valor UU",
                                        "minimum": 0,
                                        "maximum": 999999999999,
                                        "required": true
                                        },
                                    "ValU": {
                                        "description": "Valor U",
                                        "$id": "http://example.com/example.json/items/properties/paragraphs/properties/impact",
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "title": "Valor U",
                                        "minimum": 0,
                                        "maximum": 99999999999,
                                        "required": true
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
```

UUU é uma array que está recebendo o item "quantity", e esse item possui dois objetos dentro dele, preciso saber um query em Javascript para validar esses objetos dentro de "quantity". Só estou conseguindo me comunicar com o array UUU e dizer que ela possuí um item.

Comment: tentou ir pelo caminho completo? tipo Transactions.UUU.items

Comment: Tentei sim, é como se ele não conversasse com os objetos os do "quantity"

Comment: pelo q vi aqui seria entao Transactions.properties.UUU.items
se nao for, tente debugar aos poucos, um console.log(Transactions.properties) pra ver se reconhece desde o inicio

Comment: blz, vlw irmão:)